# JdbcRDD error : connection established data fetched partially

Tags: java, mysql, scala, apache-spark

I tried to connect to a mysql database, to fetch table records. I can establish the connection, and 10 records are fetched as well, but then suddenly the code crashes. I don't know why. PS: i am new to scala... Any help would be appreciated.

```
object jdbcConnect {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb" 
   val username = "root"
       val password = "token_password"
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance


       //DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

       val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JDBC RDD").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

       val myRDD = new JdbcRDD( sc, () => DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password) ,
      "select s_Id,issue_date from store_details limit ?, ?",
      0, 10, 1, r => r.getString("s_Id") + ", " + r.getString("issue_date"))

       myRDD.foreach(println)
       myRDD.saveAsTextFile("C:/jdbcrddexamplee")

  }
}
```

> ERROR
>      17/07/16 02:32:24 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
>       ExitCodeException exitCode=1: ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied. at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)

Comment: Do you have permissions to create a file in your C directory? Try My Documents instead.

Comment: @Tom yeah I suppose infact the folder does gets created

Comment: changed path. But no sucessFew records are fetched and then error

6, 1993-08-26
7, 2002-10-20
8, 2006-09-23
9, 2008-05-01
10, 2012-10-03
17/07/17 00:16:11 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 998 bytes result sent to driver
17/07/17 00:16:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 550 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
17/07/17 00:16:11 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/17 00:16:11 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (foreach at jdbcConnect.scala:34) finished in 0.570 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a permission error.
My foolishness...

Make sure to run anything as an admin.
Though i will suggest to use dataframe instead of RDD :D

Thanks